# HSL python syntax (PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, hsl

I'm having a difficult time using hsl color values in my code here... My goal is to change the opacity of a pixel in an image based on how often the coordinate's index occurs in a data set.
I'm pulling data from a csv file, and the only error I'm getting is that I'm using invalid hsl syntax. Here's a section of my code:

```
    for row in reader:
        port = int(row[0])
        opacity = int(row[1])/1000
        x = port % 255
        y = int(port/257)
        color = hsl(0, 0%, opacity)
        draw.point([(x,y)], fill=color)
        del draw
```

From PIL's website, I assumed that the lightness and saturation have to both be percentages. The maximum value that row[1] could ever be is 999, so opacity will never be >1. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried removing the percent sign so it's like this: `color = hsl(0, 0, opacity)`?

Comment: Yes, but then I get the error "name 'hsl' is not defined".

Comment: Hrm. Alternatively, have you tried `color = hsl(0, 0%, opacity%)`? Sorry -- I've never worked with PIL, just trying to give you some ideas.

Comment: Yep, I tried casting opacity as a string (does python view percentages as strings?) and adding a % to the end. The error is on the 0%, though, which is why I'm so confused.

Comment: Based on Thomas Darr's answer, I think you need to make your `color` a string, like so

`color = 'hsl(0, 0%, %d%%)' %(opacity)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PIL colors are defined as strings, not actual Python functions.

```
color = 'hsl(%d, %d%%, %d%%)' % (hue, saturation, luminance)
draw.point((x, y), fill=color)
```

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm